# CompareTo method not working

Tags: java, comparable

I am implementing a Binary Search Tree using BinaryNode to store the data. I am using a CompareTo method in my add and contains methods to determine which sub tree the item belongs in. I keep getting this error various places where compare is used:

```
BST.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
            if (item.CompareTo(root.data) > 0)
                    ^
  symbol:   method CompareTo(T)
  location: variable item of type T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class BST
```

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements BSTInterface<T>
{
    private BinaryNode<T> root;
    private int numberOfItems;
    public List<T> preOrder = new ArrayList<T>();
    public List<T> inOrder = new ArrayList<T>();
    public List<T> postOrder = new ArrayList<T>();

    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
        numberOfItems = 0;
    }

    public BST(T rootData)
    {
        root = new BinaryNode<T>(rootData);
        numberOfItems = 1;
    }

    public BST(T rootData, BST<T> leftTree, BST<T> rightTree)
    {
        root = new BinaryNode<T>(rootData);
        numberOfItems = 1;
        root.left = leftTree.root;
        root.right = rightTree.root;
    }

    public void setTree(T rootData)
    {
        root = new BinaryNode<T>(rootData);
    }

    public boolean contains(T item)
    {
        if (root.data.equals(item))
            return true;

        else
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(root.data) > 0)
            {
                root = root.left;
                return contains(item);
            }

            else if (item.CompareTo(root.data) < 0)
            {
                root = root.right;
                return contains(item);
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void add(T newItem)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new BinaryNode<T>(newItem);
            numberOfItems++;
        }

        if (newItem.equals(root.data))
            return;

        if (newItem.CompareTo(root.data) < 0)
        {
            root = root.left;
            add(newItem);
        }

        if (newItem.CompareTo(root.data) > 0)
        {
            root = root.right;
            add(newItem);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't c# :p

```
item.CompareTo()

change to:

item.compareTo()
```

`compareTo` is coming from the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing `java.lang.Comparable`, then the method should be called `compareTo()`, not `CompareTo()`.

To avoid this type of error, it is advisable to use the `@Override` annotation in front of your methods.  This way Eclipse will tell you that you are not overriding an existing method.

Answer (score 0):

`[Comparable<T>][1]` has following signature

```
int     compareTo(T o)
Compares this object with the specified object for order.
```

But you are using `CompareTo()` Please correct the case and than try

Answer (score 0):

Its `compareTo()` not `CompareTo()  // you are using capital C which is wrong`

***`int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(? super T o)`:-***

```
Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.

Finally, the implementor must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.

It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

Parameters:
o - the object to be compared.
Returns:
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
Throws:
ClassCastException - if the specified object's type prevents it from being compared to this object.
```